# Ruby Params.require.permit coming in as ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hey I am trying to figure out why when I am trying to create an article, my database is still creating an Article even though :title and :description are coming in as "". Meaning in my front end I can just hit the create button and eventhough each field is empty as in "", the article is still created and thats what I dont want to happen. If the :title param or :description param == "" I want to render an error not create an article like its currently doing.

New.hmtl.erb

```
<style>
  body {
    background-color: white !important;;
  }
</style>
<h1>Create an Article</h1>

<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <h2>The following errors have kept the article from being created</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <%end %>
  </ul>
<%end %>

<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%=f.label :title%>
      <%=f.text_field :title%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%=f.label :description%> <br/>
      <%= f.text_area :description%>
    </p>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p>

<% end %>
```

ArticlesController.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Article Successfully Created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you validating these fields for a presence in your Model? This is what your code expects. Otherwise you'll need to add other validation, perhaps in your form as well.

```
validates :description, presence: true
validates :title, presence: true
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html